# Inject a React app to another website using react-native-webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

**Background:** I'm using Expo to develop a React Native app. The purpose is to inject a React app (built code) to run as part of another website using `react-native-webview`.

**Environment:** iOS (iPhone 15 Pro simulator)

**What I have done so far:**

- I could inject some simple JS code like `alert('something')` and it worked perfectly.
- I could inject a `div` with some text to the website.

**What does not work:**

```
rootElement.innerHTML = renderToString(<div>Hello 123</div>); // does not work
root = createRoot(rootElement); // also does not work
```

Whenever I injected some `react-dom` method to the webview, it stopped working (including other alerts added above these lines).

I did try to wrap the problematic code with `try catch` in order to log the error message but it doesn't work either. It seems to me that whenever `react-dom` module is bundled into the build, the code stopped working.

**My question:**

Have you ever run into this situation? How did you solve this? I'll spend some more time to check why it's not working but before going too deep into this, I hope to receive some answers from the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could figure it out. Webpack made a separate `vendor` build (including npm modules) and I didn't include that into the injected code.

I just realized that after comparing the 2 builds: with vs. without having `react-dom`'s methods added.